# Check a condition of a data frame for each row, that is row by row

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I hava a data frame `df` with columns `a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3`. On the other hand, I have a vector `vec`.

I want to get for each row of `df` the times that the elements in the columns `b1,b2,b3` are in `vec`.

I mean, if in a row, the elements of the columns `b1` and `b2` are in `vec`, but the element of the column `b3` is not in `vec` I want to get `2`. If none of the elements of a row in the columns `b1,b2,b3` are in `vec` (also if they are missing values), I want to get `0`.

If I put `rowSums(!df[,c(b1,b2,b3)] %in% vec)`, I get the error `'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`, since the condition inside is one row, and not the number of rows of `df`. Other attempts I did also failed.

One of them: An example with just 1 row:

`df[1,c('b1','b2','b3')]:  6    -1    NA`

If I put

`df[1,c('b1','b2','b3')]==c(-1,-2)`,

I get

`FALSE    FALSE    NA`

where I would like to get

`FALSE    TRUE    NA`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `Reduce("+", lapply(df[c('b1', 'b2', 'b3')], function(x)  !x %in% vec))`

Comment: If there are `NA` values, the `==` will return `NA`.  For this you may need `& !is.na`.

Comment: This is not the problem.

Comment: I think you might have already got a warning if it is a vector  `c(6, -1, NA) == c(-1, -2)
[1] FALSE FALSE    NA`.  It is comparing with 6 with -1, -1 with -2 and NA with -1 (recycled)

Comment: Are you doing the comparison by rows?

Comment: That was the idea when I wrote `rowSums(!df[,c(b1,b2,b3)] %in% vec)`

Comment: As i said without a reproducible example, it becomes hard to know your intentions.  We don't have your `vec` nor the `df`, so I was thinking that you want to compare each column with the vec and then get the `rowSums`

Comment: anyway, I updated with some options that you can check

Comment: What I wanted is to get for each row the (number of) elements in it which are not in `vec`. Your first solution helped me. If I had time I would write a reproducible example. The vector `vec` are missing values coded numerically. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the solution could be:

```r
df %>% mutate(new = rowSums(across(matches("^b\\d$"), ~`%in%`(.,vec))))
```

With the example

```r
library(tidyverse)
vec <- c(7, 8)
df <- anscombe %>% 
          mutate(across(starts_with("y"),floor))
df
   x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 y4
1  10 10 10  8  8  9  7  6
2   8  8  8  8  6  8  6  5
3  13 13 13  8  7  8 12  7
4   9  9  9  8  8  8  7  8
5  11 11 11  8  8  9  7  8
6  14 14 14  8  9  8  8  7
7   6  6  6  8  7  6  6  5
8   4  4  4 19  4  3  5 12
9  12 12 12  8 10  9  8  5
10  7  7  7  8  4  7  6  7
11  5  5  5  8  5  4  5  6
```

one can do:

```r
df %>% 
    mutate(new = rowSums(across(starts_with("y"), ~`%in%`(.,vec))))
   x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 y4 new
1  10 10 10  8  8  9  7  6   2
2   8  8  8  8  6  8  6  5   1
3  13 13 13  8  7  8 12  7   3
4   9  9  9  8  8  8  7  8   4
5  11 11 11  8  8  9  7  8   3
6  14 14 14  8  9  8  8  7   3
7   6  6  6  8  7  6  6  5   1
8   4  4  4 19  4  3  5 12   0
9  12 12 12  8 10  9  8  5   1
10  7  7  7  8  4  7  6  7   2
11  5  5  5  8  5  4  5  6   0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%in%` works on a `vector`, so we loop through the columns of interest and get the elementwise sum with `Reduce`

```
Reduce("+", lapply(df[c('b1', 'b2', 'b3')], function(x) !x %in% vec))
```

---

If we are doing the comparison by row, then we can use `apply`

```
rowSums(t(apply(df[c('b1', 'b2', 'b3')], 1, function(x) !x %in% vec)))
```

---

Or convert it to a `matrix`, then do the comparison with `%in%`, change the dimensions and do the `rowSums`

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df[c('b1', 'b2', 'b3')])
rowSums(`dim<-`(!m1 %in% vec, dim(m1)))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, at least for what I asked. The problem I see is that it does not seem a 'natural' solution, in the sense that one should can get this 'only' with the data frame options, without having to call to `lapply` function. More than anything, because one could want partial data of some rows or something like that.

Comment: @iago  It is the limitation of `%in%`, you could use `==`, but that will be an elementwise comparison

Comment: @iago I would suggest to show a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: @iago It would not work as I said.  It will only work when you want to compare elementwise and that too after replicating to the same length

Comment: The other strange thing is that if I put `row.Sums(!is.na(df[,c(b1,b2,b3)]))`, this works well.

Comment: @iago  Honestly, I didn't get your comment `natural solution`  You mentioned that the dataset is `data.frame`, and `lapply` works for `data.frame` and if you want partial rows, just subset those rows before doing the `lapply`

Comment: @iago It is not strange.  What it does, is that you are converting to a logical matrix where TRUE is non-NA and FALSE is NA and then take the rowSums

Comment: NA is in the third column. The thing is in the second column, where there is no NA:

Comment: @iago That is why I said it is doing recycling `df[1,c('b1','b2','b3')]==c(-1,-2)` because you are comparing 3 elements with a vector of length 2.  the -1 will get repeated

Comment: I understand this. My starting idea was some substitute of `%in%` such that was applied row by row in the data frame .

Comment: @iago  The difference between `%in%` and `==` is that the former checks for all the values in the dataset instead of comparing elementwise